# Update unique matching records in same table

Tags: mysql

I have a database tables of transactions. Because of some flukes in the code, there have been a number of cases where positive transactions, and negative transactions have been made on the same invoice, in the same amount. There is a soft delete column named void. I am trying to update this, to void matching pairs.

Basically what I want is this:

```
UPDATE transactions pos JOIN transactions neg on pos.invoice_id = neg.invoice_id 
AND pos.amount = neg.amount AND pos.effect = 1 AND neg.effect = -1 
AND pos.void IS NULL AND neg.void IS NULL
SET pos.void = true, neg.void = true
```

Just running this as-is though, will not uniquely identify pairs. So, if there is a +X, -X, +X, or alternatively -Y, +Y, -Y for an invoice, it would void all. I would have thought this would be a common problem, but I am not seeing any questions or answers that quite fit my problem.

Most answers to similar questions involve using a sub-query, but they are only trying to update 1 entry, not 2, and I don't see how I'd be able to update both entries when doing that.

Thanks,
-Eric

Comment: Oh man... I had a query at my last job that did something very similar to this. It is possible, but at the moment I don't remember exactly how it worked

Answer (score 0):

maybe if you post your table structure i can help you better, but i think this is what you want:

```
UPDATE transactions
SET void = true 
WHERE invoice_id in (
    SELECT invoice_id from transactions as pos
        JOIN transactions neg 
        ON pos.invoice_id = neg.invoice_id 
        AND pos.amount = neg.amount AND pos.effect = 1 AND neg.effect = -1 
        AND pos.void IS NULL AND neg.void IS NULL
    )
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this would void all transactions for an invoice. Not just the offsetting positive and negative one.

Comment: i understand your problem now, i think it is not possible to do it in one query. I am creating a PROCEDURE for you, but i need to know what is the primary key of table transactions. Can you inform me that? or the total structure would be nice too.

Comment: I ended up getting the job done writing a php routine to iterate through the table and update entries as necessary, so I guess I have a solution. At this point I'm just curious if it could be done with a query or not, as I would learn a lot from that. The primary key is _rowid though.

Comment: I'm curious too. I think it's not possible. But, you can write a procedure and call it to get the job done. It's like do a php routine, but with more benefits:
[deinition](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-procedure.php).

Later i will update this answer with a procedure "skeleton".